# Diagram which commutes up to homotopy commutes strictly

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $M$ and $N$ be manifolds of same dimension with boundary. Let $f \colon M \to N$ be a continuous map. Apparently if the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\partial M @>>>M\\
@VVV @VVV{f}\\
\partial N @>>> N
\end{CD}

commutes up to homotopy, then there is a map $\tilde f \colon M \to N$ homotopic to $f$ such that the diagram commutes strict. I do not see why this is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because $\partial M \rightarrow M$ is a Hurewicz cofibration, and if $i:A \rightarrow X$ is a Hurewicz cofibration then if you have a diagram

[image]

which commutes up to homotopy, then you can replace $f$ by a homotopic map $\gamma$ so that the diagram

[image]

strictly commutes.

This is problem 5.3 in Jeffrey Stroms "Modern classical homotopy theory" found on page 101.

To prove that $\partial M \rightarrow M $ is a Hurewicz cofibration have a look at [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270969/is-partial-gamma-hookrightarrow-gamma-a-serre-cofibration) math overflow answer and note that all Serre cofibrations are also Hurewicz cofibrations.